# Why does the water at my sink not get hot but the shower does (same bathroom)?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I recently moved into a new house and there is one thing that baffles me and that is how the water from the sink in my bathroom will not get hot and it takes a long time for it to even get warm.  Just an arm length away is the bath/shower and that water gets hot pretty quickly.  I can turn the bathtub all the way to hot and the sink will get warm much quicker but it still doesn't get very hot.  I am not even sure where to begin.  The bathroom was rennovated at some point and my guess is it went from a one sink setup to a two sink setup, not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does your sink faucet have a single knob that controls temperature and pressure, or does it have separate knobs for hot an cold? If it's the single type it probably has some corrosion in the valve that's letting cold water in with the hot. If you've got shutoff valves for the sink faucet, turn the cold water supply off and see if it still only gets lukewarm or not.

Depending on brand and age of the faucet, you should be able to get repair parts from your local home improvement or hardware store.

Comment: It is a double knob and a rather new fixture.  I've noticed the issue is similar in the guest bath as well (new fixtures in there as well)